# Add a column in an SQL query that should only filtered results

Tags: sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have the below table:

```
TABLE
+--------------------------+
| STUDENT  CLASS     SCORE |
+--------------------------+
| Student1 Science   Pass  |
| Student1 Math      Fail  |
| Student1 Geography Fail  |
| Student2 Science   Pass  |
| Student2 Math      Pass  |
| Student2 Geography Fail  |
+--------------------------+
```

I'd like to see results as follows

```
+------------------------------------+
| STUDENT  Science   Math  Geography |
+------------------------------------+
| Student1 Pass     Fail   Fail      |
| Student2 Pass     Pass   Fail      |
+------------------------------------+
```

Any idea on how I can do so this?

Comment: Please note the edits to reformat your question properly, and if you have any updates to make then please retain the formatting (or at least, something better than the original).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed list of classes, you can just use conditional aggregation:

```
select student,
    max(case when class = 'Science'   then score end) as science,
    max(case when class = 'Math'      then score end) as math,
    max(case when class = 'Geography' then score end) as geography
from mytable
group by student
```

Comment: this worked like a charm!! thank you for the quick response!!